# Ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' with template template arguments

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm trying to make a template class where one would be able to define the (STL) container used by the class as a template parameter. So I did the following:

```
template <typename T = float,
          template < class, class > class Container = std::vector,
          class Alloc = typename std::vector < Spectrum < T > >::allocator_type>
class Spectrogram;
```

My problem is that when I define my overload for the stream operator as

```
// Definition inside the 'public' part of the 'Spectrogram' class
template <typename Type,
          template < class, class > class C,
          class A>
friend std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream &, const Spectrogram < Type, C, A > & );

// Implementation
template <typename Type,
          template < class, class > class C,
          class A>
std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & o, const Spectrogram < Type, C, A > & s )
{
   // Transparent implementation
   return o;
}
```

and then create some test code as

```
Spectrogram < float > spectrogram;
// Fill the spectrogram etc. -- codepart omitted
std::cout << spectrogram;
```

I get the following error:

```
Ambiguous overload for 'operator<<'
```

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks for any help,
Ádám

P.S. The referenced classes have the following definitions:

```
// Spectrum
template < typename T = float, class Container = std::vector < T > > class Spectrum {
public:
   typedef T ( * WindowFunction ) ( const T & );
   typename Container::const_iterator begin ( void ) const;
   typename Container::const_iterator end ( void ) const;
   typename Container::const_reverse_iterator rbegin ( void ) const;
   typename Container::const_reverse_iterator rend ( void ) const;
   WindowFunction getWindowFunction ( void ) const;
   typename Container::size_type getWindowSize ( void ) const;
   typename Container::size_type getFFTSize ( void ) const;
   void setWindowFunction ( const WindowFunction & );
   void setFFTSize ( const typename Container::size_type & );
   template < class InputIterator > void import ( const InputIterator &, const InputIterator & );
   template < typename Type, class C > friend std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream &, const Spectrum < Type, C > & );
protected:
   WindowFunction windowFunction;
   typename Container::size_type windowSize;
   Container spectrum;
   void clear ( void );
};

// Spectrogram
template < typename T = float, template < class, class > class Container = std::vector, class Alloc = typename std::vector < Spectrum < T > >::allocator_type > class Spectrogram {
public:
   typedef typename Container < Spectrum < T >, Alloc >::const_iterator Iterator;
   typedef typename Container < Spectrum < T >, Alloc >::const_reverse_iterator ReverseIterator;
   typedef typename Container < Spectrum < T >, Alloc >::size_type size_type;
   Iterator begin ( void ) const;
   Iterator end ( void ) const;
   ReverseIterator rbegin ( void ) const;
   ReverseIterator rend ( void ) const;
   size_type size ( void ) const;
   bool empty ( void ) const;
   WindowTypes getWindowType ( void ) const;
   double getHopFactor ( void ) const;
   unsigned long getWindowSize ( void ) const;
   unsigned short getOversamplingFactor ( void ) const;
   unsigned long getHopSize ( void ) const;
   void setWindowType ( const WindowTypes & );
   void setHopFactor ( const double & );
   void setWindowSize ( const unsigned long & );
   void setOversamplingFactor ( const unsigned short & );
   template < class InputIterator > void import ( const InputIterator &, const InputIterator & );
   template < typename Type, template < class, class > class C, class A > friend std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream &, const Spectrogram < Type, C, A > & );
protected:
   Container < Spectrum < T >, Alloc > spectrogram;
   double hopFactor;
   unsigned long windowSize;
   unsigned short oversamplingFactor;
   WindowTypes windowType;
};
```

I'm using GCC 4.2 with XCode 4.0.2.

Comment: Not sure why this question got downvoted. Seems like a reasonable question even if I don't know the answer offhand.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, it's a good question - but I did get halfway through the question before my brain gave up on it... That's more to do with c++ template syntax than the question though :)

Comment: We could get a hint if the compiler tells you **which** overloads are considered.

Comment: It's probably the same thing about template friends that should have tons of duplicates. - The template template parameters might also make it more complicated: why not a single Container parameter? You can get the `value_type` from that.

Comment: Your code compiles fine under GCC 4.6.1. Also, you might consider making the friend a non-template and define it inline.

Comment: Compiles under GCC 4.3 and 4.4, but 4.1 gives an error similar to what you describe. Must be a GCC bug.

Comment: Addition: if you define (not just declare) `operator<<` inline, the error goes away even under 4.1.

Comment: @n.m I'd like to accept your answers (telling that in 4.4 and 4.3 it compiles fine and in 4.1 it needs the declaration inline). Could you please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiles under GCC 4.3 and 4.4, but 4.1 gives an error similar to what you describe. Must be a GCC bug.

Answer (score 2):

Although it seems the problem is solved by a compiler upgrade or minor syntactic adjustment, you might want to simplify the parameterization.

`class Spectrogram` only really depends on the class used to contain its data. So this would work with no loss of functionality:

```
template< typename Container >
class Spectrum {
public:
    typedef typename Container::value_type value_type;
    ...
};

template< typename Container >
class Spectrogram {
    // assume Container::value_type is a specialization of Spectrum
    typedef typename Container::value_type::value_type numeric_type;
};
```

This eliminates the cascading sequence of default arguments, but greatly simplifies the design. You can again simplify usage by providing `typedef`s and (if you're really using a variety of parameterizations) metafunctions that map the desired parameters to the required `Container`.

```
typedef Spectrum< vector< float > > Spectrum_sp; // single-precision
typedef Spectrograph< Spectrum_sp > Spectrograph_sp;
```